# Check if any solution exists

Tags: prolog

I have some code in the form

```
plan([],_).
plan([ Item | RemainingItems ], Groups) :-
  doStuff(Groups, Item, UpdatedGroups),
  rulesObeyed(UpdatedGroups),
  plan(RemainingItems, UpdatedGroups).
```

doStuff only have one possible sub tree, but the rulesObeyed can have endless based on the number of groups as the rules can be obeyed in several ways.
This results in that plan returns the same solutions over and over.

Is there any way to say something like

```
solution_exists(rulesObeyed(UpdatedGroups))
```

so it does not take all the possible solutions to rulesObeyed into account?

Comment: And 5 seconds after I ask I find once/1... - have I understood it correctly, that it checks that there is an solution?

Comment: yes, "once" is what you are looking for.

Comment: You might use `\+ \+ Goal` or `once(Goal)`. As long as `Goal` is a ground term, there is no (logical) difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `once/1` - or `\+ \+` as false posted.